# Numpy slice not updating as expected

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I've written an algorithm for LU decomposition of a square matrix. Problem I'm facing is that the values in a NumPy 2-d array **slice** are **not updating as expected**. See the image at the bottom.

The matrix A is defined as follows:

```
A = np.array([[1, -3, 5, 2], [1, 0, 1, -1], [6, 1, -9, 2], [1, 0, -6, 3]])
```

The Algorithm:

```
def LUGAUSS(A):
  if A.shape[0] != A.shape[1]:
    return "Invalid Matrix. A must be a square marix."

  multipliers = dict()
  for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    print('i',i)
    if A[i,i] == 0:
      return "Pivot is zero"
    else:
      multipliers[(i+1,i)] = A[i+1:,i] / A[i,i]
      A[i+1:,i] =  multipliers[(i+1,i)] # <- !!This line is the problem!!
      A[i+1:,i+1:] = A[i+1:,i+1:] -  A[i+1:,i].reshape(-1,1) * A[i,i+1:].reshape(1,-1)
     
    
  L = np.eye(A.shape[0])
  for x in range(L.shape[1]):
    L[x+1:,x] = multipliers[(x+1,x)]

  U = A.copy()
  for x in range(U.shape[1]):
    U[x+1:,x] = 0 

  return (L,U,multipliers)
```

The Following update should change [6,1] to [6.333,1].

See the image:

[image: Img]

Answer (score 0):

`B` is an integer array, so the incoming values are being cast to integers.  If you need floats. you should use `astype` to convert `B` to float64.